# Oscillations of a plunger in an ideal gas with adiabatic processes

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, mass, harmonic-oscillator

I am trying to find the frequency of the oscillations of a plunger of mass $m$ and area $A$ within a closed equilibrium at both ends. If in the equilibrium state it divides the cylinder into two equal volumes $V_1$. The gas pressure is $p_1$ and the processes are considered adiabatic.

Could you give me an idea?

Comment: What were the original conditions (pressure, volume) on each side of the plunger before the oscillations began.

Comment: In the equilibrium state the piston divides the cylinder into two equal volumes V1 and the gas pressure is p1.

Comment: Aren't you describing the final equilibrium state after the oscillations cease? What was the initial equilibrium state and what caused the oscillations? Typically, it would be the result of some kind of unrestrained expansion of the gas on one side of the plunger.  You need to be clear in describing the actual process that caused the oscillations, or risk having your question closed.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry. In the equilibrium state the piston divides the balance into two equal volumes Vo and the gas pressure is po. The plunger is then moved slightly from the equilibrium position and released. The processes must be considered adiabatic and the friction is negligible.

Comment: Express the force as a function of the area and the pressure of the gas at equilibrium, but when it begins to oscillate, do not understand how to relate the adiabatic process to the oscillations.

Comment: OK, so the plunger is initially in equilibrium dividing the chamber in half with equal pressures on each half. Then it is moved from its equilibrium position. That means there is an increase in pressure  and decrease in volume on the side where it was moved. I'm not certain, but you may need to specify what that pressure and volume is as it may influence the oscillation. If you move it infinitesimally, then maybe there will be  no oscillation at all if the process is considered reversible.

Comment: Yes, but what would be the role of the gamma factor?

Comment: If as a result of displacing and releasing the plunger the plunger undergoes oscillation, then you have an irreversible process. For an irreversible adiabatic process the equation $pV^Υ$=constant does not apply.

Comment: Oh, thank you very much

Comment: I think it is valid to use the reversible process results if the amplitude of the oscillation is very small.

Comment: @BobD Do you agree with my comment that, for large plunger masses and small displacements, it is valid to consider the oscillation process reversible?  I can prove that this is the case if you wish.

Comment: @ChetMiller Chet, yes I agree. I commented to OP that if the displacement is infinitesimally small the process could be considered reversible.

Comment: @ChetMiller I guess the only reservation I have is regarding damping. If the small amplitude oscillations  are not damped (i.e. ideal spring) then clearly its reversible. But if the oscillations cease how do we consider the viscous loss? Are we saying the loss is infinitessimal?

Comment: @BobD If the parameters are chosen right, the viscous dissipation will be negligible; and a small amount of amplitude damping won't significantly affect the frequency.  Even in just plain expansions and compressions, we only approach reversibility in the limit of vanishingly slow deformation rate.  This can be quantified once the frequency is established by using it to calculate the elongational deformation rate of the gas.  This can be used to estimate the average rate of viscous dissipation per unit volume.

Comment: @ChetMiller You explanation is perfect. Whether we are making infinitesimal changes in a  single direction and stopping or alternatively in different directions (oscillating), we are dealing with infinitesimal disequilibrium.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hint:  If the piston is displaced a distance $\delta$ to the right (where $\delta$ is small) and the adiabatic relation $PV^{\gamma}=P_1V_1^{\gamma}$ applies, by how much does the pressure increase and decrease in each of the compartments?  What is the net force on the plunger $\delta F$?  What is the "spring constant"?